# MUI DataGrid: Responsive mobile layout

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So the desktop query for datagrid looks good, however I think it needs a mobile media query (exactly like this: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)
I am dealing with data from an api so I can't do what theyre doing with the text on the css.

I've been searching the mui docs for 4 days with no luck.
Does anybody have any ideas as to how to do this with DataGrid?

Comment: I've the same problem? any adeas please?

Comment: as far as I know its not support out the box, you would need to do some serious overhauling to get that to work. MUIDatatables provides this functionality but we just moved away from it due to lack of continuing support and constant issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done.
I've made a Table component that looks at the media query and renders Desktop or Mobile table component depending on the media query:

```
import useTheme from '@mui/system/useTheme';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';
import TableMobile from './TableMobile';
import TableDesktop from './TableDesktop';

function Table(props) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isSmScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

  return isSmScreen ? <TableMobile {...props} /> : <TableDesktop {...props} />;
}

export default Table;
```

Nothing special on the table desktop, it is just a regular MUI table that takes and displays the data.

Below is the mobile table component, the trick is with the tableCellStyles, it takes a data attribute to display the column header. I basically ditched TableHead and went with a Rows approach.

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import {
  useTable,
  usePagination,
  useFilters,
  useGlobalFilter,
  useExpanded,
} from 'react-table';

import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import TableFooter from '@mui/material/TableFooter';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination';
import MobileTableNavigation from './MobileTableNavigation';

const tableCellStyles = {
  display: 'block',
  '&::before': {
    content: 'attr(data-label)',
    float: 'left',
    fontWeight: 700,
  },

  fontSize: '12px',
  color: '#fff',
};

export default function TableMobile({
  data,
  columns,
  rowsPerPageOptionsMobile = [3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
  initialStateMobile = {
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 3,
  },
  autoResetPage = true,
}) {
  // react-table requires a default column when using filters.
  const defaultColumn = useMemo(
    () => ({
      Filter: <></>,
    }),
    []
  );

  const {
    gotoPage,
    setPageSize,
    pageOptions,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    page: rows, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
    // which has only the rows for the active page
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable(
    {
      defaultColumn,
      columns,
      autoResetPage,
      data,
      initialState: initialStateMobile,
    },
    useFilters,
    useGlobalFilter,
    useExpanded,
    usePagination
  ); // react-table hooks

  return (
    <>
      <Paper sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table {...getTableProps()}>
            <TableFooter>
              <TableRow>
                <TablePagination
                  rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptionsMobile}
                  component="div"
                  sx={{
                    '& .MuiToolbar-root': {
                      width: '100%',
                      gap: '10px',
                    },

                    '& .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows': {
                      order: 0,
                      flex: 1,
                      position: 'absolute',
                      left: '22px',
                      color: '#fff',
                    },

                    '& .MuiTablePagination-selectLabel': {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },

                    '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
                      '.MuiTablePagination-select': {
                        display: 'flex',
                        width: '30px',
                        border: '1px solid',
                        borderColor: 'primary.linkColor',
                        borderRadius: '5px',
                        color: 'primary.linkColor',
                      },

                      '.MuiTablePagination-selectIcon': {
                        color: 'primary.linkColor',
                      },
                    },
                  }}
                  count={rows.length}
                  rowsPerPage={pageSize}
                  page={pageIndex}
                  onPageChange={gotoPage}
                  onRowsPerPageChange={(e) =>
                    setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
                  }
                  labelRowsPerPage="Results per page:"
                  labelDisplayedRows={() =>
                    `${pageIndex + 1}-${pageOptions?.length} of ${
                      pageOptions?.length
                    }`
                  }
                  ActionsComponent={() => <></>}
                />
              </TableRow>
            </TableFooter>
          </Table>
          <Table
            sx={{
              borderCollapse: 'collapse',
              margin: 0,
              padding: 0,
              width: '100%',
              tableLayout: 'fixed',
            }}
            size="small">
            <TableBody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {rows.map((row) => {
                prepareRow(row);

                return (
                  <>
                    <TableRow
                      {...row.getRowProps()}
                      key={row?.id}
                      sx={{
                        display: 'block',
                        padding: '0.35em',
                        borderBottom: '27px solid #F1F1F1',
                        boxShadow: 'inset 0 -7px 10px -11px',
                      }}>
                      {/* dont include the id field */}
                      {row.cells.map((cell, idx) => {
                        return (
                          <TableCell
                            key={idx}
                            data-label={cell.column.Header || 'ERR::NO_HEADER'}
                            align="right"
                            sx={tableCellStyles}
                            {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                            {cell.render('Cell')}
                          </TableCell>
                        );
                      })}
                    </TableRow>
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
      <MobileTableNavigation
        currentPage={pageIndex}
        onPageChange={gotoPage}
        rowsPerPage={pageSize}
        totalRowsCount={data.length}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

and just in case. Here is the desktop table component for you, so you can see the difference in the order of the components and the style choices.

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import {
  useTable,
  usePagination,
  useFilters,
  useGlobalFilter,
  useExpanded,
} from 'react-table';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

// components
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import TableFooter from '@mui/material/TableFooter';
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

// icons
import FirstPageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FirstPage';
import LastPageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LastPage';
import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowLeft';
import KeyboardArrowRight from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tableRoot: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: '1100px',
  },
  tableContainer: {
    maxHeight: 500,
  },
  tableBody: {
    background: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  pagination: {
    background: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  paginationSpacer: {
    flex: '1 1 100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      flex: '0 0',
    },
  },
  paginationActions: {
    flexShrink: 0,
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(2.5),
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      flexShrink: 1, // direction buttons in a column in small screen
    },
  },
  tableHeader: { maxWidth: '200px', width: '250px' },
  tableHead: {
    background: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function TableDesktop({
  columns,
  data,
  autoResetPage = true,
  initialStateDesktop = {
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
    // filters: [{ id: 'isActive', value: true }],
  },
  filterColumnProps,
  rowsPerPageOptionsDesktop = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100],
}) {
  // react-table requires a default column when using filters.
  const defaultColumn = useMemo(
    () => ({
      Filter: <></>,
    }),
    []
  );

  const {
    gotoPage,
    setPageSize,
    pageOptions,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page: rows, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
    // which has only the rows for the active page
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable(
    {
      defaultColumn,
      columns,
      autoResetPage,
      data,
      initialState: initialStateDesktop,
    },
    useFilters,
    useGlobalFilter,
    useExpanded,
    usePagination
  ); // react-table hooks

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <TableContainer className={classes.tableContainer}>
        <Table stickyHeader className={classes.table} {...getTableProps()}>
          <TableHead className={classes.tableHead}>
            {/* COLUMN HEADERS */}
            {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column, key) => {
                  return (
                    <TableCell
                      key={key}
                      {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                      className={classes.tableHeader}>
                      <Grid container direction="column">
                        <Grid item>{column.render('Header')}</Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                          {column.canFilter
                            ? column.render('Filter', filterColumnProps) // pass props to column
                            : null}
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                    </TableCell>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHead>

          <TableBody {...getTableBodyProps()} className={classes.tableBody}>
            {rows.map((row, idx) => {
              prepareRow(row);
              // table rows
              return (
                <TableRow tabIndex={-1} {...row.getRowProps()} hover key={idx}>
                  {row.cells.map((cell, idx) => {
                    return (
                      // cell of row.
                      <TableCell
                        key={idx}
                        style={{ maxWidth: '200px' }}
                        {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                        {cell.render('Cell')}
                      </TableCell>
                    );
                  })}
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableFooter>
          <TableRow>
            {/* TABLE PAGINATION */}

            {/* Material UI TablePagination component */}
            <TablePagination
              rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptionsDesktop}
              colSpan={0}
              className={classes.pagination}
              count={pageOptions.length}
              rowsPerPage={pageSize}
              onPageChange={gotoPage}
              page={pageIndex}
              labelRowsPerPage="Results per page:"
              classes={{ spacer: classes.paginationSpacer }}
              onRowsPerPageChange={(e) => setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))}
              labelDisplayedRows={() =>
                `${pageIndex + 1}-${pageOptions?.length} of ${
                  pageOptions?.length
                }`
              }
              ActionsComponent={(props) => {
                const { page, onPageChange } = props;

                const canGoNext = page < pageOptions?.length - 1;
                const canGoBack = page > 0;

                const handleFirstPageButtonClick = () => {
                  onPageChange(0);
                };

                const handleBackButtonClick = () => {
                  // if (!canPreviousPage) return;
                  if (!canGoBack) return;

                  const previousPage = page - 1;
                  onPageChange(previousPage);
                };

                const handleNextButtonClick = () => {
                  // if (!canNextPage) return;
                  if (!canGoNext) return;

                  const nextPage = page + 1;
                  onPageChange(nextPage);
                };

                const handleLastPageButtonClick = () => {
                  // onPageChange(Math.max(0, Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1));
                  onPageChange(pageOptions?.length - 1);
                };

                return (
                  <div className={classes.paginationActions}>
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={handleFirstPageButtonClick}
                      disabled={page === 0}
                      aria-label="first page">
                      <FirstPageIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={handleBackButtonClick}
                      disabled={page === 0}
                      aria-label="previous page">
                      <KeyboardArrowLeft />
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={handleNextButtonClick}
                      // disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
                      disabled={!canGoNext}
                      aria-label="next page">
                      <KeyboardArrowRight />
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={handleLastPageButtonClick}
                      // disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
                      disabled={!canGoNext}
                      aria-label="last page">
                      <LastPageIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </div>
                );
              }}
            />
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came searching for possible answers as well - I think Im comitted to defining 2 datagrids, one for desktop, one for mobile - and showing one or the other.